# Fetching methods depends on each other

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying to fetch data from two sources in componentDidMount and   second component's url relies on the data fetched from the first component, but it looks that state is not "updated" inside ComponenDidMount. I have tried to resolve it by using fetchDuel() in the constructor with no luck. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
class DuelDetail extends React.Component {
    state = {
        duel: [],
        dataset: null
    };


    fetchDuel = () => {
        const duelID = this.props.match.params.duelID;
        axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/duel/${duelID}`,
            {'headers': {'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}})
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    duel: res.data
                });
            });
    };

    fetchDataset = () => {
        axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dataset/${this.state.duel.dataset}`,
            {'headers': {'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}})
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    dataset: res.data
                });
            });
    };


    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchDuel()
        this.fetchDataset()
    }
```

Comment: Look into axios.all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call the second function in the `then()` block of the first and pass the data as a param. `setState` is asynchronous so you can't rely on the data to be set immediately.

```js
fetchDuel = () => {
        const duelID = this.props.match.params.duelID;
        axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/duel/${duelID}`,
            {'headers': {'Authorization': `Token                                ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}})
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    duel: res.data
                });
                this.fetchDataset(res.data);
            });
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

As the 2 actions are async you need to handle it accordingly.

Axios get returns a promise .So you can call the second action in the then block of the first action.

Also, setState is an aync action.(It gets queued up and doesn't get triggered instantly).
Use the data received from the first action, in its then block, pass it to the second action

Answer (score 0):

Just call the second function in the `.then()` of the first function using data from the response. Example:

```js
class DuelDetail extends React.Component {
    state = {
        duel: [],
        dataset: null
    };


    fetchDuel = () => {
        const duelID = this.props.match.params.duelID;
        axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/duel/${duelID}`,
            {'headers': {'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}})
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    duel: res.data
                });
                
                this.fetchDataset(res.data.dataset) 
                // pass whatever property you get from the response here.
            });
    };

    fetchDataset = (datasetId) => {
        axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dataset/${datasetId}`,
            {'headers': {'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}})
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    dataset: res.data
                });
            });
    };


    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchDuel()
    }
```